# I get the changelog when upgrading using apt-get

Tags: apt

I am getting a weird issue when running `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

This is on Ubuntu Server 13.10

[image: ISSUE]

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>q</kbd> to exit this info screen.

To get rid of it in the future remove `apt-listchanges` package with:

```
sudo apt-get remove apt-listchanges
```